# Is there a way to do cross site script (XSS) testing using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, xss, security-testing

Given that JMeter is not a browser and only simulates the actions of a browser, has anyone ever attempted to do cross-site script testing using JMeter?. I was reading online some articles about how to do security testing using JMeter but I didn't come across any work elaborating any attempts to do cross-site script testing.

I have done performance testing using JMeter, but I can't think of any way performing an XSS test using JMeter. So would love to hear, ideas and thought in this regard, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jmeter is mainly meant for performance and load testing. Also a little bit of automation can also be done with jmeter(even though you can get better tools for automation out there). Again , regarding security testing, yes it can be done by providing xss scripts in parameters and request headers of requests and then bombarding to the server. Also you can do ddos attack with jmeter. But for these kind of penetration testinh you have better tools out there. I suggest you to do penetration testing witj owasp zap and to do it in a professional way. Install a kali linux and do ethical hack.